# Data type for point coordinates input in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point

I am working in QGIS console. I'd like to create new point in existing layer and using two floats as coordinates [1604288.165, 642862.0068].

```
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(coords[0], coords[1]))
```

But getting TypeError ((

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 80, in <module>
TypeError: QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

Into which type should I convert my coordinates?

Comment: Check this article [How to input a point coordinates in PyQGIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350224/how-to-input-a-point-coordinates-in-pyqgis) and try what @BERA recommended

Comment: Thank you, @Taras!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fromPointXY` creates a new geometry from a [`QgsPointXY`](https://qgis.github.io/pyqgis/3.4/core/QgsPointXY.html#module-QgsPointXY) object which is created by providing two coordinates:

```
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(coords[0], coords[1])))
```